Verilog clock implementation gone wrong
I just started learning Verilog and made a system clock and its respective testbench, but it is getting stuck in an infinite loop in the testbench. Could you please help me?
Below is the implementation of system clock and clock testbench respectively.
It is supposed to give me a clock of time-period 10ns, duty 50% and is supposed to reset whenever reset signal is set(1) it is supposed to set clock to 0 as long as reset stays 1.
The test bench got stuck in an infinite loop.
I am using Iverilog version 12.0
CLK.v
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps

    module clock_generator(
        input wire reset,      // Reset input
        output reg clk       // Clock output
    );
        parameter frequency = 1e8; // in Hz
        parameter duty = 0.50; // Duty in fraction
        parameter tp = (1/frequency) * 1e9;
        parameter cycle = tp*duty; // High Low cycle

        initial begin
            clk = 1'b0;
        end

        always begin
            if (reset) begin
                clk = 1'b0;   // Reset clock to 0
            end else begin
                clk = 1'b1;   // Set clock high
                #(cycle) clk = 1'b0; // High phase duration
                #(tp - cycle); // Low phase duration
            end
        
        end
    
endmodule

//CLK_tb.v

    `timescale 1ns / 1ns
    `include "CLK.v"

    module CLK_tb;
        reg reset;
        wire clk;

        // Instantiate the clock module
        clock_generator UUT (
            .clk(clk),
            .reset(reset)
        );

        initial begin
            $dumpfile("Clk_tb.vcd");
            $dumpvars(0, CLK_tb);

            // Apply the reset pattern
            reset = 1'b0;  // Start with reset = 0
            #30;          // Hold reset = 0 for 30ns
            reset = 1'b1;  // Set reset to 1
            #10;          // Hold reset = 1 for 10ns
            reset = 1'b0;  // Clear reset
            #50;          // Hold reset = 0 for 50ns
            reset = 1'b1;  // Set reset to 1
            #30;          // Hold reset = 1 for 30ns
            reset = 1'b0;  // Clear reset

            #100;         // Run simulation for an additional 100ns
            $display("Simulation over.");
            $finish;       // End the simulation
        end
    endmodule


In Verilog, all processes share the global concept of simulated time. If one process get stuck in a loop without delays, none of the other processes can advance in simulation time until something breaks that infinite loop. This infinite loop is what happens when reset become true in your example.
There are a couple ways to handle this.
You can split your clock generator into 2 processes, and use a procedural assign or force statement that overrides the assignments in the other process. This essentially gates the clock generator
always @*
            if (reset) 
                assign clk = 1'b0;   // Reset clock to 0
              else
                deassign clk;
always begin
          clk = 1'b1;   // Set clock high
          #(cycle) clk = 1'b0; // High phase duration
          #(tp - cycle); // Low phase duration
       end

You could also do this in a single process using a wait blocking statement
    always begin
            if (reset) begin
                clk = 1'b0;   // Reset clock to 0
                wait(!reset);
            end else begin
                clk = 1'b1;   // Set clock high
                #(cycle) clk = 1'b0; // High phase duration
                #(tp - cycle); // Low phase duration
            end
        
        end


The infinite loop is in the clock_generator module:
    always begin
        if (reset) begin
            clk = 1'b0;   // Reset clock to 0
        end else begin

When the testbench sets reset to 1, the if clause is true, and the always block keep triggering in zero time.
One way to solve the problem is to add a delay inside the if clause, for example:
    always begin
        if (reset) begin
            clk = 1'b0;   // Reset clock to 0
            #1;
        end else begin

This change avoids the infinite loop.  You need to decide if the #1 is appropriate delay value for your code.
